# Как правильно писать условие на клик

Tags: javascript, jquery, if

Добрый вечер, интересует вопрос по поводу синтаксиса условия, нужно повесить событие при нажатии одной из кнопок как будет собственно выглядеть синтаксис самого условия
что то вроде:

```
if($("button_1").click() || $("button_2").click() || $("button_3").click()) {
  Дальше код события...
}
```

Не знаю будет ли вообще подобное условие работать, но нужно узнать какое лучше писать подобные логические куски?

Comment: попробуйте конкретнее сформулировать: что конкретно вы хотите сделать

Comment: @Grundy Ну не знаю куда конкретнее, я хочу чтобы при нажатии на одну из МНОЖЕСТВА кнопок срабатывало условие к примеру тот же alert("Hello world"), вопрос в том чтобы вы подсказали как лучше писать такое условие для множества кнопок с разными идентификаторами. Выше я привел пример кода (не факт что рабочего) что бы вам было удобней понять что мне нужно.

Comment: @Doofy Насколько я понимаю, код осознанно написан на несуществующем языке программирования с просьбой перевести на яваскрипт.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky, При текущем раскладе проверка сработает один раз в условии, это если написать метод, который будет возвращать в это условие true или false. Я так понял, что при любом нажатии кнопки нужно чтобы сработало условие, но на js нужно вешать обработчики

Comment: @Doofy Если я правильно понял, автор хочет научиться вешать один общий обработчик на произвольный набор кнопок. А код в вопросе - это вообще не код, а метафора, мираж, расплывчатый образ идеи, которую автор хочет воплотить в жизнь. Оценивать этот код по каким-либо правилам - лишнее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<button class='button_1'>button 1</button>
<button class='button_2'>button 2</button>
```

С помощью JavaScript

```
buttons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.button_1, .button_2'));
buttons.forEach(function(button) {
    button.onclick = function() {
        console.log('hello world');
    }
});
```

---

С помощью jQuery

```js
$('.button_1, .button_2').on('click', function() {
    console.log('hello world');
});
```

```js
$('.button_1, .button_2').click(function() {
    console.log('hello world');
});
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '.button_1, .button_2', function() {
    console.log('hello world');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Все очень просто:

```js
$(".one, .two, .three").click(function () {
  alert("Clicked "+$(this).attr("class"));
  // дальше код события
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="one">Click me!</button>
<button class="two">Click me 2!</button>
<button class="three">Click me 3!</button>
```

Comment: Вы немного не поняли мне нужен пример синтаксиса такого вот события только при условии if чтобы можно было указать в условии несколько кнопок при помощи оператора or

Comment: так указывайте CSS селектором через запятую. Сейчас обновлю ответ

Answer (score 0):

Или без jquery:

```
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(function (element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', function () {
        /* код */
    });
});
```

Comment: так не сработает, у коллекции. которую возвращает _querySelectorAll_ нет метода _forEach_

Comment: @Grundy попробуй в консоли написать `typeof document.querySelectorAll("*").forEach`

Comment: Попробуй сделать это где-то кроме хрома :) например в firefox нет такого метода, в EDGE и IE тоже

Comment: ну и [по спецификации](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177) такого метода тоже нет.